# Sharepoint 2013 Quick Launch fly out menu formatting

Tags: quick-launch

I have setup a fly-out menu in Quick Launch the funtionality works fine. However, many of the items are wrapping and the window that pops up is undersized.

I was able to resolve that on the Top Menu by using the CSS word-wrap property, but cannot see where to do this with the Quick Launch.

Please let me know a solution if you have one!